# Можно ли подключить flask-admin к postgresql не используя классы?

Tags: python, postgresql, flask-admin

Во всех примерах в интернете используется примерно такая схема(P.S. код может быть не верным, не суть важно, главное оформление):

```
class HardwareView(ModelView):
    # Disable model creation
    can_create = True

    # Override displayed fields
    column_list = ('model', 'max_nics')

    column_display_all_relations = True
    column_searchable_list = ('model')
    column_labels = dict(model='Model', max_nics='Max Nics')
    form_columns = ['model', 'max_nics' ]

    def __str__(self):
        return self.model


admin = Admin(app, name="MyApp1")
# Add administrative views here
admin.add_view(ModelView(Server, db.session))
admin.add_view(ModelView(Hardware, db.session))
```

Но у меня уже создана таблица в postgresql через pgAdmin4. Получается, мне нужно будет её удалить и создать новую через class, как в примере.
Могу ли я связать таблицу, созданную в pgAdmin4 с flask-admin без создания и использования классов?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если хочешь использовать ORM то придется создавать классы для моделей.
Если данные в таблице уже есть, то можно использовать 2 варианта:

1. Создать модель таблицы аналогичную структуре.
2. Создать новую таблицу, а данные просто перелить из одной в другую.